# We can create any key by using two primary key of other table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a database design document in which they mentioned FK_Ref as comma separated primary keys of other tables. My question is that is it possible to use comma separated values into a column as a key in mysql.

Comment: I think you are confused about how a composite key works.  A composite key is one which is made up of two or more keys.  Putting CSV data into any column in a SQL database usually isn't recommended, because it is hard to work with such data.

Comment: It seems the database design document is trying to treat a N:M relationship between tables like a 1:N relationship, avoiding an intermediate table. This is undesirable in most of the cases because you won't be able to easily perform joins between these tables

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241953/sql-query-of-multiple-values-in-one-cell/24242119#24242119 for how to perform a join with a comma-separated value, using the `FIND_IN_SET()` function. But it will be slow because it can't be indexed. You should use a many-to-many relationship table instead.